# How can I disable this lines in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, underline

How can I disable these orange & blue lines that are under my code on line 3 & 4? It's a mess when there is a lot of code.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85B6o.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most probably `"editor.guides.bracketPairsHorizontal"`.

See if this setting exists in your `settings.json`; if it's there, it's probably set to `true`.

You can set it to `"active"` to only show up for the scope where your caret is or to `false` to never show at all.